# Link invariants from modular categories (strictification and computation)

Tags: knot-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, monoidal-categories, computer-algebra, quantum-topology

By the theory of Reshetikhin and Turaev, a modular tensor category $C$ gives rise to a link invariant. While $C$ is strict as a monoidal category (e.g. $\mathbb{Fib}$), calculating the link can be made much easier by considering matrices of complex matrices [1]. It's even implemented into a mathematica package [2].

Though many modular categories are not strict (e.g those that arise from quantum groups), any monoidal category is **explicitly** *monoidally equivalent* to a strict monoidal category [3]. I thus wonder if the link invariants after strictification remain the same - **If that is the case, then the mathematica package can be used to compute any link invariants of this sort.**

#### An explicit description of the strictification

This section is taken from [3].

Let $C$ be a monoidal category (with associator $\alpha$) and $D$ to be the monoidal category of right $C$-module endofunctors of $C$. It's easy to see that $D$ is strict, and easy to construct a monoidal equivalence $C \mapsto{F} D$ that sends a $C$-object $X$ to a $D$-object $(X \otimes -, \alpha_{X,-,-})$. The technical "$J$"-structure of $F$ is provided by

$$J = \alpha^{-1}_{X,Y,-}.$$

#### Reference

- [1] [Representing modular tensor categories: a computer algebra system for topological quantum computing](https://ora.ox.ac.uk/objects/uuid:c9b6eaf8-29d4-4637-a576-5a35d3c957bb)
- [2] [User Guide for TwoVect.m](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/jamie.vicary/twovect/guide.pdf)
- [3] Theorem 2.8.5, Tensor Categoies by Etingof et al.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you have equivalent ribbon categories then they give the same link invariants.  This is just saying you can define the invariant in the language of ribbon categories.  A helpful analogy is why any statement you can make in the language of groups will stay the same if you replace the group by an isomorphic group.

(I should be slightly more careful, these depend on a ribbon category and a choice of object to label the diagram.  So really you should have an equivalence $F: C \rightarrow D$ and an iso for the chosen objects $f: F(c) \rightarrow d$.  But again any statement in the language of ribbon categories with a chosen object will be invariant under such equivalences.)

Comment: I was confused.. it doesn't seem to work directly as there might not be a modular structure for $D$ such that the given equivalence is an equivalence of MTC. For example, take the Fibonacci modular category.. can you find an equivalence modular category that is strict? [Recall](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0712.1377.pdf) from 5.3.2 that Fib has nontrivial F matrix.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what you’re asking. Is your question whether if you have a tensor equivalence $F: C \rightarrow D$ and C has a ribbon structure does D also have a ribbon structure in a way that makes F an equivalence of ribbon categories?